# How to access only first element and no array from the given object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to access only the object like it list blizzard, bubblebeam etc skipping everythin in []?
and results will be parsed with commas if possible. Please help me i am a noob :(
my `set.js`

```
missingno: {learnset: {
        blizzard: ["5L1"],
        bubblebeam: ["5L1"],
        cut: ["5L1"],
        doubleedge: ["5L1"],
        earthquake: ["5L1"],
        fissure: ["5L1"],
        fly: ["5L1"],
        icebeam: ["5L1"],
        megakick: ["5L1"],
        megapunch: ["5L1"],
        psychic: ["5L1"],
        rage: ["5L1"],
        razorwind: ["5L1"],
        rest: ["5L1"],
        seismictoss: ["5L1"],
        skyattack: ["5L1"],
        submission: ["5L1"],
        swordsdance: ["5L1"],
        takedown: ["5L1"],
        teleport: ["5L1"],
        thunder: ["5L1"],
        thunderwave: ["5L1"],
        toxic: ["5L1"],
        triattack: ["5L1"],
        watergun: ["5L1"],
    }},
```

Code that i am currently using but it is returing everything.

```
const dex = require("sets.js").BattleLearnsets;
poke = "missingno";
JSON.stringify(dex[poke].learnset)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i understood from you question is you only need keys not the values

```
var z ={ missingno: {learnset: {
    blizzard: ["5L1"],
    bubblebeam: ["5L1"],
    cut: ["5L1"],
    doubleedge: ["5L1"],
    earthquake: ["5L1"],
    fissure: ["5L1"],
    fly: ["5L1"],
    icebeam: ["5L1"],
    megakick: ["5L1"],
    megapunch: ["5L1"],
    psychic: ["5L1"],
    rage: ["5L1"],
    razorwind: ["5L1"],
    rest: ["5L1"],
    seismictoss: ["5L1"],
    skyattack: ["5L1"],
    submission: ["5L1"],
    swordsdance: ["5L1"],
    takedown: ["5L1"],
    teleport: ["5L1"],
    thunder: ["5L1"],
    thunderwave: ["5L1"],
    toxic: ["5L1"],
    triattack: ["5L1"],
    watergun: ["5L1"],
}}}
Object.keys(z.missingno.learnset);
// Output array of keys  ["blizzard", "bubblebeam", "cut", "doubleedge", "earthquake", "fissure", "fly", "icebeam", "megakick", "megapunch", "psychic", "rage", "razorwind", "rest", "seismictoss", "skyattack", "submission", "swordsdance", "takedown", "teleport", "thunder", "thunderwave", "toxic", "triattack", "watergun"]
```

Answer (score 0):

get by keys by `Object.keys` and for first take `array` 0 position

```js
let obj = {missingno :{learnset: {
        blizzard: ["5L1"],
        bubblebeam: ["5L1"],
        cut: ["5L1"],
        doubleedge: ["5L1"],
        earthquake: ["5L1"],
        fissure: ["5L1"],
        fly: ["5L1"],
        icebeam: ["5L1"],
        megakick: ["5L1"],
        megapunch: ["5L1"],
        psychic: ["5L1"],
        rage: ["5L1"],
        razorwind: ["5L1"],
        rest: ["5L1"],
        seismictoss: ["5L1"],
        skyattack: ["5L1"],
        submission: ["5L1"],
        swordsdance: ["5L1"],
        takedown: ["5L1"],
        teleport: ["5L1"],
        thunder: ["5L1"],
        thunderwave: ["5L1"],
        toxic: ["5L1"],
        triattack: ["5L1"],
        watergun: ["5L1"],
    }}};
console.log(Object.keys(obj.missingno.learnset)[0]);
console.log(obj.missingno.learnset[Object.keys(obj.missingno.learnset)[0]]);
```